# timer gets executed twice.. in java

Tags: java, timer, timertask

Facing terrible issue... .

I have two timers of Class java.util.Timer, scheduledReportTimer which sends daily emails and scheduleImmediateReportTimer which send emails on every 10 mins.
    scheduledReportTimer is working perfectly fine.
    scheduleImmediateReportTimer is runs every 10 mins but it seems its running twice in 10 mins or there are two thread gets created for scheduleImmediateReportTimer (i am not sure what exactly it is)
    but it is calling the email sending method twice 
    i tested email sending logic for lots of conditions and which is perfect .

please help me.

```
public class ScheduleReportManager implements ServletContextListener{

    private ServletContext application  = null;
    private Environment environment =null;
    private Timer scheduledReportTimer=null;
    private Timer scheduleImmediateReportTimer=null; //daily timer 
    private ConcurrentHashMap scheduledReportTimerTasks;
    private ConcurrentHashMap scheduledImmediateReportTimerTasks; //daily timer hash map
    ApplicationContext webContext=null;

    public ScheduleReportManager() {
    }
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {

        try{
            this.application= servletContextEvent.getServletContext();
            webContext = (ApplicationContext) application.getAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE);

            //daily timer 
            if(application.getAttribute("scheduledReportTimer")==null)
            {
                application.setAttribute("scheduleReportManager",this);
                this.scheduledReportTimer= new Timer(true);
                setupSchedule(scheduledReportTimer, application);
                application.setAttribute("scheduledReportTimer", scheduledReportTimer);
            }

            //timer for 10 mins
            if(application.getAttribute("scheduleImmediateReportTimer")==null)
            {
                this.scheduleImmediateReportTimer= new Timer(true);
                setupImmediateSchedule(scheduleImmediateReportTimer, application);
                application.setAttribute("scheduleImmediateReportTimer", scheduleImmediateReportTimer);
            }
            Logger.global.log(Level.INFO, "ScheduledReportTimer: " + application.getServletContextName() + ": Setup completed");
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.global.log(Level.SEVERE, "Setup Report Timer Exception - " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    //timer for 10 mins
    public void setupImmediateSchedule(Timer scheduledImmediateReportTimer,ServletContext application ) {
        scheduledImmediateReportTimerTasks= new ConcurrentHashMap();
        ScheduleImmediateReportTimerTask immediateReportTimerTask = new ScheduleImmediateReportTimerTask(application,environment,this);
        scheduledImmediateReportTimerTasks.put(environment.getCode(),immediateReportTimerTask);
        scheduledImmediateReportTimer.schedule(immediateReportTimerTask,1000);
    }

    //timer for 10 mins
    public void setTimerForImmediateReportExecution(ScheduleImmediateReportTimerTask immediateReportTimerTask){

        Environment environment = immediateReportTimerTask.getEnvironment();
        ServletContext application = immediateReportTimerTask.getApplication();
        ScheduleImmediateReportTimerTask reportTimerTask= new ScheduleImmediateReportTimerTask(application,environment,this);
        String environmentCode = environment.getCode();

        synchronized (scheduledImmediateReportTimerTasks){
            scheduledImmediateReportTimerTasks.put(environmentCode,reportTimerTask);
            scheduleImmediateReportTimer.schedule(reportTimerTask,600000);      // set timer for running every 10 mins
        }
    }

    //daily timer 
    public void setTimerForNextExecution(ScheduledReportTimerTask timerTask, DateTime nextExecutionDateTime)
    {
        if(nextExecutionDateTime == null)
            return;

        Environment environment = timerTask.getEnvironment();
        ServletContext application = timerTask.getApplication();
        ScheduledReportTimerTask scheduledReportTimerTask =  new ScheduledReportTimerTask(application,environment,this);
        java.util.Date nextScheduleTime = nextExecutionDateTime.getDate();
        String environmentCode = environment.getCode();
        synchronized (scheduledReportTimerTasks){
            scheduledReportTimerTasks.put(environmentCode,scheduledReportTimerTask);
            Logger.global.log(Level.INFO, "ScheduledReportManager: next execution time is " + nextScheduleTime.toString());
            scheduledReportTimer.schedule(scheduledReportTimerTask,nextScheduleTime);
        }
    }
    //daily timer 
    public void setupSchedule(Timer scheduledReportTimer,  ServletContext application) throws Exception{
        this.environment = SpringBridgeUtil.retrieveEnvironment(application);
        this.scheduledReportTimerTasks= new ConcurrentHashMap();
        ScheduledReportTimerTask scheduledReportTimerTask = new ScheduledReportTimerTask(application,environment,this);
        scheduledReportTimerTasks.put(environment.getCode(),scheduledReportTimerTask);
        scheduledReportTimer.schedule(scheduledReportTimerTask,1000);
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        String contextName = application.getServletContextName();
        if (scheduledReportTimer != null) {
            scheduledReportTimer.cancel();
        }
        if(scheduleImmediateReportTimer !=null)
        {
            scheduleImmediateReportTimer.cancel();
        }
        Logger.global.log(Level.INFO, "scheduledReportTimer: " + contextName
                + ": Tasks cancelled due to context removal");
    }

}

// sends email on every 10 mins
public class ScheduleImmediateReportTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{

            // send mail 
            sendNotifiationEmail();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Logger.global.log(Level.INFO,"immediateScheduledReportTimerTask Exception " + e.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

i am using jdk 1.7 and spring mvc 3.5.0 .
Classes using java.util.Timer and import java.util.TimerTask;

Let me know if this is the correct way or is there any other way to get execute schedule task periodically .

Comment: Check out AlarmManager... it's better for timing stuff, especially for those long intervals like days.... plus it keeps working when your app is destroyed, which your solution doesn't...

Comment: Theres also Quartz, I love Quartz.

Comment: Thank you for your reply .. do you see any issue with my code using Timer please ?